# Why can we assume that these eignenfunctions are known, in the Sturm-Liouville problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Consider the following heat equation PDE, with non-constant coefficients. That is $c = c(x)$, $\rho = \rho(x)$, and $K_0 = K_0(x)$

\begin{align} 
\begin{cases}
c \rho u_t = (K_0 u_x)_x \\ u(x,0) = f(x) \\ 
   u(0,t) = u_x(L,t) = 0 \\ t\geq 0, \,\,  0\leq x\leq L
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Separation of variables gives rise to the Sturm-Liouville ODE for the spatial function $\phi(x)$
\begin{align}
(K_0 \phi')' + \lambda c \rho \phi = 0  
\end{align}

Here my textbook states that while the eigenfunctions $\phi_n$ might be difficult to calculate (and will most likely be done numerically), that nevertheless they can be calculated. So we can continue our solution analysis assuming the eigenfunctions $\phi_n$ are known.

That's where my question comes in; how would we calculate the eigenfunctions given that our eigenvalues are still unknown? Rayleigh's quotient for calculating *eigenvalues* wouldn't work because $\phi_n$ is yet unknown. How can I be confident that $\phi_n(x)$ is known?

Comment: There is some unhelpful ambiguity in your use of "known": do you mean "known to exist", or, instead, "known-in-some-detail" in some way? Probably your textbook means that it is "known" that there is an orthonormal basis (for some suitable Hilbert space, say) consisting of eigenfunctions. E.g., there is no "continuous spectrum", and no other hijinx.

Answer (score 0):

> how would we calculate the eigenfunctions given that our eigenvalues are still unknown?

By replacing the eigenfunction problem with its discretization: finite difference method, or finite element method, and solving the resulting linear system. There are books written about numerical methods for differential equations, including eigenproblems; check out some. There is also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory#Representation_of_solutions_and_numerical_calculation).